# Force confirmation dialog "wants to open facebook"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-login

Who knows how to restore this "XXX wants to open 'facebook'" confirmation message on iOS 12? Only shows the first time I used it (in my app), but I need to try again many times to test the flow process. How can I force to request me any time (or everytime I need to test it)?
Thank you so much!

[image: dialog flow process I need to repeat]

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?